# How to have a 1 letter/digit representation for range 1 to 35 numbers using PHP

Tags: php

I have to create a BATCH sequence and there is one digit slot for revision count.

This revision count can be in the range starting from 0 to 35 numbers.

What will be the largest possible range for single digit/letter representation.

Now i am using hexdec function and it seems they are looking for more range.

Or lets say what is the largest range possible for 1 digit/letter representation?

Below is my code:

```
Case:
0 = 0
. 
.
10 = A
11 = B
.
.
32 = ?

// $revcount can be from 1 to 16
$revcount = dechex($revcount);
```

Thanks to @Narf :)

ANSWER:

```
$dd = 35;
echo "NUMBER  IS = $dd \n";
$dd = base_convert($value = $dd , 10, 36);
$string = $dd;
echo "STRING  IS = $string \n";
$ss = intval($value = $string,  36);
echo "REVERSE IS = $ss \n";
```

Comment: Digit obviously would be 9 as the range of a single digit would be 0-9, do you mean character?

Comment: do you mean something like your own dictionary? 0=0, ..9=9, a = 10, ..A=36... ?

Comment: it can go to lets say from integer 0 to 32 or more but we need to have a single digit representation. lets say for 10 it will be like "A" which is hexdec representation for 10.

Comment: Ok, but A isn't a digit, it's a character.  So you may want to update your question.  Digits = 0-9

Comment: yup sorry for confusion yes it can be letter as well but it can take only one space for 2 digits!

Comment: updated question

Comment: Technically, 'A' *is* a digit in the hexadecimal system. :) But yes, it is a bit unclear ... Digit vs character vs byte - all different things.

Comment: @Narf yes, I guess mathematically that is true, just never heard anything but 0-9 be referred to as digit.  English, Arabic, and Latin definition of digit seems to be 0-9, based off of base 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

35 is the largest value in base-36 ... Also the maximum allowed with [base_convert()](https://secure.php.net/base_convert), so it's easily achievable in PHP:

```
base_convert($value = 35, $baseFrom = 10, $baseTo = 36); // returns 'z'
```

Of course, a raw byte could accomodate a wider range, but I assume that we talk about human-readable data here.

Comment: awesome!! it worked can we do the reverse for this as well.. like if we have "Z" can we convert it back to 35?

Comment: can you help me with function name to do that, i have never used this function like this!

Comment: I think intval is the function.... am still learning new things in php... will give it a try and will let you know!

Comment: Um ... no: `base_convert('z', 36, 10); // returns 35`

Comment: `intval('z', 36); // this also returns 35`

Comment: yup you are right! Thanks for the perfect solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

hexdec range is 16, (0-9,A-F)

alphanumerical would be 36 (0-9, A-Z)

if you include symbols, theoretically you could get as high as 256 on a single byte or character.  8 bits = 1 byte, a bit can be 0 or 1, hence 2^8 (256).  Play around with http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php